# server.html not found while creating an Express Based Server

Tags: javascript, express

Here is my code:

```
const express = require('express');
var app = express();
const nunjucks = require('nunjucks');
nunjucks.configure('templates', {
    autoescape: true,
    express: app
});
let host = '127.0.3.1'; 
let port = '9233'; 
let myName = '[RETACTED]';
var d = new Date();
let date = d.getMonth() + "/" + d.getDay() + "/" + d.getFullYear();
let time = Date.now();

let info = {host: host, port: port, name: myName, date: date, time: time}

app.get('/date', function (req, res) {
    res.render('server.html', info);
});

app.listen(port, host, function () {
    console.log("Example app listening on IPv4: " + host +
    ":" + port);
});
```

I tried running it on Git Bash, but an error saying this appeared:

```
Error: template not found: server.html
    at createTemplate (C:\Users\Default.DESKTOP-7TNLM47\repo\practice\node_modul
es\nunjucks\src\environment.js:290:15)
    at next (C:\Users\Default.DESKTOP-7TNLM47\repo\practice\node_modules\nunjuck
s\src\lib.js:330:7)
    at handle (C:\Users\Default.DESKTOP-7TNLM47\repo\practice\node_modules\nunju
cks\src\environment.js:329:11)
    at C:\Users\Default.DESKTOP-7TNLM47\repo\practice\node_modules\nunjucks\src\
environment.js:339:9
    at next (C:\Users\Default.DESKTOP-7TNLM47\repo\practice\node_modules\nunjuck
s\src\lib.js:328:7)
    at Object.asyncIter (C:\Users\Default.DESKTOP-7TNLM47\repo\practice\node_mod
ules\nunjucks\src\lib.js:334:3)
    at Environment.getTemplate (C:\Users\Default.DESKTOP-7TNLM47\repo\practice\n
ode_modules\nunjucks\src\environment.js:321:9)
    at Environment.render (C:\Users\Default.DESKTOP-7TNLM47\repo\practice\node_m
odules\nunjucks\src\environment.js:360:10)
    at NunjucksView.render (C:\Users\Default.DESKTOP-7TNLM47\repo\practice\node_
modules\nunjucks\src\express-app.js:22:9)
    at tryRender (C:\Users\Default.DESKTOP-7TNLM47\repo\practice\node_modules\ex
press\lib\application.js:640:10)
Error: template not found: server.html
    at createTemplate (C:\Users\Default.DESKTOP-7TNLM47\repo\practice\node_modul
es\nunjucks\src\environment.js:290:15)
    at next (C:\Users\Default.DESKTOP-7TNLM47\repo\practice\node_modules\nunjuck
s\src\lib.js:330:7)
    at handle (C:\Users\Default.DESKTOP-7TNLM47\repo\practice\node_modules\nunju
cks\src\environment.js:329:11)
    at C:\Users\Default.DESKTOP-7TNLM47\repo\practice\node_modules\nunjucks\src\
environment.js:339:9
    at next (C:\Users\Default.DESKTOP-7TNLM47\repo\practice\node_modules\nunjuck
s\src\lib.js:328:7)
    at Object.asyncIter (C:\Users\Default.DESKTOP-7TNLM47\repo\practice\node_mod
ules\nunjucks\src\lib.js:334:3)
    at Environment.getTemplate (C:\Users\Default.DESKTOP-7TNLM47\repo\practice\n
ode_modules\nunjucks\src\environment.js:321:9)
    at Environment.render (C:\Users\Default.DESKTOP-7TNLM47\repo\practice\node_m
odules\nunjucks\src\environment.js:360:10)
    at NunjucksView.render (C:\Users\Default.DESKTOP-7TNLM47\repo\practice\node_
modules\nunjucks\src\express-app.js:22:9)
    at tryRender (C:\Users\Default.DESKTOP-7TNLM47\repo\practice\node_modules\ex
press\lib\application.js:640:10)
```

However, the server.html is in the same folder as the server.js. Is there any solution I could use to fix it? I'm kind of a beginner at creating servers with JS and I probably need some guidance here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you've configured nunjucks to look up the views in the `templates` directory (in the `nunjucks.configure` call), you should move the `server.html` file to the `templates` directory.

Comment: I created a templates directory in my nunjunks folder via node-modules and put my HTML file in that folder just now, but it's still showing the error...

Comment: Oh, nevermind, I put the full path of the folder and it worked. Thanks!